# Passing and using Class in a method in Java

Tags: java, class, parameters, parameter-passing

```
void methodA() {
  methodB(ClassA.class)
}

void methodB(Class classname) {
  classname a; //not correct
  HashMap<String, classname> hash = new HashMap<>(); //not correct
}
```

IDE is complaining it to be not correct.

I want to do something like what is being commented as //not correct. Why is it not correct and how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a variable name as a type name, so `methodB` won't compile.

You can however use a type parameter for the method.  Try

```
<T> void methodB(Class<T> clazz) {
    T a;
    HashMap<String, T> hash = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Comment: `methodB(ClassA.class)` will still be the same? `T` is red. It asks me to create class T. Why is there a `<T>` before void methodB?

Comment: Yes, you can still pass in `ClassA.class`.  It will control what type `T` is inferred to be.

Comment: The `<T>` declares a generic type parameter for the method, making `T` in scope for the method.  This should work for Java 1.5+ (when generics were introduced).

Comment: When you call `methodB`, pass `ClassA.class` as an argument to `methodB`.  In `methodB`, the parameter `clazz` is assigned the value passed in - `ClassA.class`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variable name as type of any method that has to passed as parameter. Else it will give compilation error.